# Is the projective dimension of modules with finite projective dimension bounded?

Tags: commutative-algebra, projective-module

I know that a Noetherian local ring $R$ has finite global dimension if and only if $R$ is regular in which case $\mathrm{gldim}{R} = \dim{R}$. Therefore, for regular rings, every module has projective dimension at most $\dim{R}$. When $R$ is not regular there must exist modules with infinite projective dimension.

My question is:

> For $R$ Noetherian local but not regular, do there exist modules with finite but arbitrarily large projective dimension or are the projective dimensions of modules with $\mathrm{pd}(M) < \infty$ bounded? If so, are they bounded by $\dim{R}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll assume all rings are commutative. In this case, your question was answered precisely by Auslander and Buchsbaum in "Homological dimension in local rings". [Link!](https://doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9947-1957-0086822-7)

The answer is yes: these finite projective dimensions are bounded by the Krull dimension of $R$!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. To check, this is true even for modules that are not finitely generated, correct? When $M$ is finitely generated I know that $\mathrm{pd}(M) \le \dim{R}$ by the Auslander Buchsbaum formula.

Comment: Apologies, I was unclear -- this is for finitely generated modules. Indeed, this paper is the origin of the Auslander-Buchsbaum formula. For general modules, the remarkable answer is that the finite projective dimensions are still bounded, and in fact the maximum finite projective dimension is always exactly $\operatorname{dim}(R)$! This is a theorem of Reynaud and Gruson, from "Critères de platitude et de projectivité" (Theoreme 3.2.6)

Comment: So, in short, yes, this bound holds for all modules.